# Future-proof eGPU enclosure for Macbook

Tags: graphics-cards

With the vast amount of graphics card enclosures appearing on the market, I need some help choosing a future-proof one with the following guidelines:

I have a Mid-2015 MacBook Pro (2,5 GHz Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM, AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB) and I would like to drive two external 2k monitors with a secondary graphics card and enclosure. This specific MacBook only supports Thunderbolt 2, therefore the enclosure has to be compatible with this revision of the Thunderbolt technology.

Since I may upgrade my MacBook to the latest model at some point, I would like the enclosure to be able to make sure of it - therefore it has to support Thunderbolt 3 ports, too.

I would like to use the GPU enclosure with OS X and Windows.

In addition: I am going to live in Germany, the US and Canada in the next two years so it would be nice, if the enclosure would support all these power plugs/voltages.

Comment: I highly doubt there is an enclosure that has _native_ support for TB2 _and_ TB3. However, I _think_ you could use a TB2 <=> TB3 adapter when you get the new laptop (these should be a thing for the apple users who want to continue using their old HW, like you).

Comment: I would actually suggest that you get a Thunderbolt 3 (from enclosure) to Thunderbolt 2 (Computer input) adaptor, and use the Razer Core as the GPU enclosure. The problem with doing it the other way is because you will be limiting your bandwidth.

Comment: I have agree with Edward on the adapter question now, but oppose him on the choice of enclosure, the Razer core has about _the worst_ amount of features for the price tag.